# References to generic type Map<K,C> should be parameterized

Tags: java, eclipse

In an abstract class is the following abstract method definition:

```
public abstract Map<String, String> aMethod(aType type);
```

I am unable to prevent this warning in Eclipse:

> References to generic type Map should be parameterized

I've been searching around and can't seem to work this out. I've found others experiencing the same error, but in their cases it seemed to make sense. In mine I can't see the logic.

I could suppress warnings, but I'd like to understand what's going wrong before implementing a workaround.

Thanks.

Comment: Eclipse has a habit of not recognizing when you've fixed things like that. Try rebuilding/compiling the project and the warning will probably disappear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Map` is already parameterized, so the warning does not make sense. Try cleaning your project.

Comment: Cleaning fixed it; thanks! I'll keep that in mind next time I have similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

This warning is propably caused by something like

```
public Map aMethod(aType type);
```

The difference to this:

```
public Map<String, String> aMethod(aType type);
```

is that the latter creates a Map that you can only put Strings inside, but you can be sure that you always get Strings when requesting a value. The former makes you able to put everything inside it, but you can't be sure what you will get when fetching a value off the Map.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the error is up to date with the file?

This compiles without a warning:

```
import java.util.Map;
class aType {}

public abstract class Main {
    public abstract Map<String, String> aMethod(aType type);
}
```

This however produces the error you describe:

```
import java.util.Map;
class aType {}

public abstract class Main {
    public abstract Map aMethod(aType type);
}
```